# Simulation of Quantum Ising Model

Tags: simulations, ising-model

I curious to know if there is a way to do simulation of quantum ising model with transverse field.

The method I know is - do classical ising model simulation in d+1 dimension which essentially maps to d dimensional ising model by Suzuki-Totter formalism.

But I was wondering if simulation of ground state of ising model is doable. Like, instead of spins $=\pm 1$, we take angle and rest things appropriately.

Comment: In which dimension?

Comment: @norbertschuch One dimension.

Comment: The method of choice would be DMRG.

Comment: What do you mean by "we take angle and rest things appropriately"? Anyway, I agree with Norbert Schuch. DMRG would be the best way to compute the ground state of the quantum Ising model.

Comment: @DelCrosB A spin half state can be represented on Bloch Sphere $|\theta,\phi\rangle$. Idea is to generate two random numbers to change spin state $|\theta,\phi\rangle$ instead of spin flip in typical classical ising model monte carlo simulation. The problem however would be - we would have result for non zero finite temperature.